# how to restrict future months in jquery monthpicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I wish to disable the future months and display the months till the current month in jquery monthpicker. Here is the code

```
var picker = jQuery('#SearchVal').MonthPicker({
 maxDate: "0m",
ShowIcon: false,
OnAfterChooseMonth: function(){
    var elts = picker.val().split('/');
    picker.val(monthsLabels[parseInt(elts[0])-1]+', '+elts[1]);
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can try this. This is working for me.

$('#my_widget').monthpicker('disableMonths', [1, 2, 11, 12]);
$('#my_widget').monthpicker('disableMonths', []); // re-enables all months
```

Reference From : Month Picker Jquery->lucianocosta.info/jquery.mtz.monthpicker/

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all the months after the current from the month list and pass the list as a parameter to the `monthpicker`.

```
var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
var current = new Date().getMonth();
months.splice(0, current);
var picker = jQuery('#SearchVal').MonthPicker({
    maxDate: "0m",
    ShowIcon: false,
    month: months,
    OnAfterChooseMonth: function(){
      var elts = picker.val().split('/');
      picker.val(monthsLabels[parseInt(elts[0])-1]+', '+elts[1]);
    }
});
```

Comment: I put this code. But there is no change. Can you please suggest some other method

Answer (score 0):

At last i found the solution for this. This is working for me.

```
var months = new Array();
var j = 0;
for (var i = <?=date('n')?>+1; i <= 12; i++)
{
    months[j++] = i;
}

jQuery('#SearchVal').monthpicker({startYear:2000,finalYear:<?=date('Y')?>,pattern:'yyyy-mm'});
for(var i = 0; i < jQuery('#SearchVal').length; i++){
jQuery(jQuery('#SearchVal')[i]).monthpicker("disableMonths",months);
jQuery(jQuery('#SearchVal')[i]).monthpicker().bind('monthpicker-change-year', function(e, year){

var item = jQuery(e.currentTarget);
if(year === '<?=date("Y")?>'){
 jQuery(item).monthpicker('disableMonths', months);
} else {
jQuery(item).monthpicker('disableMonths', []);
}
});
```